# kubectl patch can't be applied to ConfigMap data

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

## What happened:

When I applied patch to ConfigMap, it doesn't work well. (`Error from server: v1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadString: expects " or n, but found {, error found in #10 byte of ...|"config":{"template"|..., bigger context ...|{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"config":{"template":{"containers":[{"lifecycle":{"preStop":|...`)

gsed works fine, but I want to know `kubectl

### Command

```
$ kubectl patch configmap/cm-test-toshi -n dev --type merge -p '{
  "data":{
    "config":{
      "template":{
        "containers":[{
          "name":"istio-proxy",
          "lifecycle":{
            "preStop":{
              "exec":{
                "command":[\"/bin/sh\", \"-c\", \"while [ $(netstat -plunt | grep tcp | grep -v envoy | wc -l | xargs) -ne 0]; do sleep 1; done\"]
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

### Target CondigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |-
    policy: disabled
    alwaysInjectSelector:
      []
    neverInjectSelector:
      []
    template: |
      initContainers:
      - name: istio-validation
      ...
      containers:
      - name: istio-proxy
      {{- if contains "/" (annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image) }}
        image: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image }}"
      {{- else }}
        image: "{{ .Values.global.hub }}/{{ .Values.global.proxy.image }}:{{ .Values.global.tag }}"
      {{- end }}
        ports:
        ...
```

## What you expected to happen:

No error occurs and `data.condif.template.containers[].lifecycle.preStop.exec.command` is applied.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |-
    policy: disabled
    alwaysInjectSelector:
      []
    neverInjectSelector:
      []
    template: |
      initContainers:
      - name: istio-validation
      ...
      containers:
      containers:
      - name: istio-proxy
        lifecycle:     # added
          preStop:   # added
            exec:       # added
              command:  ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while [ $(netstat -plunt | grep tcp | grep -v envoy | wc -l | xargs) -ne 0 ]; do sleep 1; done"] # added
      {{- if contains "/" (annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image) }}
        image: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image }}"
      {{- else }}
        image: "{{ .Values.global.hub }}/{{ .Values.global.proxy.image }}:{{ .Values.global.tag }}"
      {{- end }}
        ports:
        ...
```

## How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):

1. Create ConfigMap

```
$ kubectl apply -f cm-test-toshi.yaml
```

cm-test-toshi.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |-
    policy: disabled
    alwaysInjectSelector:
      []
    neverInjectSelector:
      []
    template: |
      {{- $cniDisabled := (not .Values.istio_cni.enabled) }}
      {{- $cniRepairEnabled := (and .Values.istio_cni.enabled .Values.istio_cni.repair.enabled) }}
      {{- $enableInitContainer := (or $cniDisabled $cniRepairEnabled .Values.global.proxy.enableCoreDump) }}
      rewriteAppHTTPProbe: {{ valueOrDefault .Values.sidecarInjectorWebhook.rewriteAppHTTPProbe false }}
      {{- if $enableInitContainer }}
      containers:
      - name: istio-proxy
      {{- if contains "/" (annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image) }}
        image: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image }}"
      {{- else }}
        image: "{{ .Values.global.hub }}/{{ .Values.global.proxy.image }}:{{ .Values.global.tag }}"
      {{- end }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15090
          protocol: TCP
          name: http-envoy-prom
        args:
        - proxy
        - sidecar
        - --domain
        - $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.{{ .Values.global.proxy.clusterDomain }}
        - --configPath
        - "/etc/istio/proxy"
        - --binaryPath
        - "/usr/local/bin/envoy"
        - --serviceCluster
        {{ if ne "" (index .ObjectMeta.Labels "app") -}}
        - "{{ index .ObjectMeta.Labels `app` }}.$(POD_NAMESPACE)"
        {{ else -}}
        - "{{ valueOrDefault .DeploymentMeta.Name `istio-proxy` }}.{{ valueOrDefault .DeploymentMeta.Namespace `default` }}"
        {{ end -}}
        - --drainDuration
        - "{{ formatDuration .ProxyConfig.DrainDuration }}"
        - --parentShutdownDuration
        - "{{ formatDuration .ProxyConfig.ParentShutdownDuration }}"
        - --discoveryAddress
        - "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/discoveryAddress` .ProxyConfig.DiscoveryAddress }}"
      {{- if eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "lightstep" }}
        - --lightstepAddress
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetLightstep.GetAddress }}"
        - --lightstepAccessToken
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetLightstep.GetAccessToken }}"
        - --lightstepSecure={{ .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetLightstep.GetSecure }}
        - --lightstepCacertPath
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetLightstep.GetCacertPath }}"
      {{- else if eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "zipkin" }}
        - --zipkinAddress
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetZipkin.GetAddress }}"
      {{- else if eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "datadog" }}
        - --datadogAgentAddress
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetDatadog.GetAddress }}"
      {{- end }}
        - --proxyLogLevel={{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/logLevel` .Values.global.proxy.logLevel}}
        - --proxyComponentLogLevel={{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/componentLogLevel` .Values.global.proxy.componentLogLevel}}
        - --connectTimeout
        - "{{ formatDuration .ProxyConfig.ConnectTimeout }}"
      {{- if .Values.global.proxy.envoyStatsd.enabled }}
        - --statsdUdpAddress
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.StatsdUdpAddress }}"
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.global.proxy.envoyMetricsService.enabled }}
        - --envoyMetricsServiceAddress
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetEnvoyMetricsService.GetAddress }}"
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.global.proxy.envoyAccessLogService.enabled }}
        - --envoyAccessLogServiceAddress
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.GetEnvoyAccessLogService.GetAddress }}"
      {{- end }}
        - --proxyAdminPort
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.ProxyAdminPort }}"
        {{ if gt .ProxyConfig.Concurrency 0 -}}
        - --concurrency
        - "{{ .ProxyConfig.Concurrency }}"
        {{ end -}}
        {{- if .Values.global.controlPlaneSecurityEnabled }}
        - --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
        - MUTUAL_TLS
        {{- else }}
        - --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
        - NONE
        {{- end }}
        - --dnsRefreshRate
        - {{ valueOrDefault .Values.global.proxy.dnsRefreshRate "300s" }}
      {{- if (ne (annotation .ObjectMeta "status.sidecar.istio.io/port" .Values.global.proxy.statusPort) "0") }}
        - --statusPort
        - "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `status.sidecar.istio.io/port` .Values.global.proxy.statusPort }}"
        - --applicationPorts
        - "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/applicationPorts` (applicationPorts .Spec.Containers) }}"

      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.global.trustDomain }}
        - --trust-domain={{ .Values.global.trustDomain }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.global.logAsJson }}
        - --log_as_json
      {{- end }}
      {{- if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/bootstrapOverride`) }}
        - --templateFile=/etc/istio/custom-bootstrap/envoy_bootstrap.json
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.global.proxy.lifecycle }}
        lifecycle:
          {{ toYaml .Values.global.proxy.lifecycle | indent 4 }}
        {{- end }}
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: INSTANCE_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        - name: HOST_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
      {{- if eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "datadog" }}
      {{- if isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `apm.datadoghq.com/env` }}
      {{- range $key, $value := fromJSON (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `apm.datadoghq.com/env`) }}
        - name: {{ $key }}
          value: "{{ $value }}"
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_POD_PORTS
          value: |-
            [
            {{- $first := true }}
            {{- range $index1, $c := .Spec.Containers }}
              {{- range $index2, $p := $c.Ports }}
                {{- if (structToJSON $p) }}
                {{if not $first}},{{end}}{{ structToJSON $p }}
                {{- $first = false }}
                {{- end }}
              {{- end}}
            {{- end}}
            ]
        - name: ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID
          value: "{{ valueOrDefault .Values.global.multiCluster.clusterName `Kubernetes` }}"
        - name: ISTIO_META_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: ISTIO_META_CONFIG_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: SDS_ENABLED
          value: "{{ .Values.global.sds.enabled }}"
        - name: ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE
          value: "{{ or (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/interceptionMode`) .ProxyConfig.InterceptionMode.String }}"
        - name: ISTIO_META_INCLUDE_INBOUND_PORTS
          value: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts` (applicationPorts .Spec.Containers) }}"
        {{- if .Values.global.network }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_NETWORK
          value: "{{ .Values.global.network }}"
        {{- end }}
        {{ if .ObjectMeta.Annotations }}
        - name: ISTIO_METAJSON_ANNOTATIONS
          value: |
                 {{ toJSON .ObjectMeta.Annotations }}
        {{ end }}
        {{ if .ObjectMeta.Labels }}
        - name: ISTIO_METAJSON_LABELS
          value: |
                 {{ toJSON .ObjectMeta.Labels }}
        {{ end }}
        {{- if .DeploymentMeta.Name }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME
          value: {{ .DeploymentMeta.Name }}
        {{ end }}
        {{- if and .TypeMeta.APIVersion .DeploymentMeta.Name }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_OWNER
          value: kubernetes://apis/{{ .TypeMeta.APIVersion }}/namespaces/{{ valueOrDefault .DeploymentMeta.Namespace `default` }}/{{ toLower .TypeMeta.Kind}}s/{{ .DeploymentMeta.Name }}
        {{- end}}
        {{- if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/bootstrapOverride`) }}
        - name: ISTIO_BOOTSTRAP_OVERRIDE
          value: "/etc/istio/custom-bootstrap/custom_bootstrap.json"
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.global.sds.customTokenDirectory }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_SDS_TOKEN_PATH
          value: "{{ .Values.global.sds.customTokenDirectory -}}/sdstoken"
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.global.meshID }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_MESH_ID
          value: "{{ .Values.global.meshID }}"
        {{- else if .Values.global.trustDomain }}
        - name: ISTIO_META_MESH_ID
          value: "{{ .Values.global.trustDomain }}"
        {{- end }}
        {{- if and (eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "datadog") (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `apm.datadoghq.com/env`) }}
        {{- range $key, $value := fromJSON (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `apm.datadoghq.com/env`) }}
          - name: {{ $key }}
            value: "{{ $value }}"
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
        imagePullPolicy: "{{ valueOrDefault .Values.global.imagePullPolicy `Always` }}"
        {{ if ne (annotation .ObjectMeta `status.sidecar.istio.io/port` .Values.global.proxy.statusPort) `0` }}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz/ready
            port: {{ annotation .ObjectMeta `status.sidecar.istio.io/port` .Values.global.proxy.statusPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: {{ annotation .ObjectMeta `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/initialDelaySeconds` .Values.global.proxy.readinessInitialDelaySeconds }}
          periodSeconds: {{ annotation .ObjectMeta `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/periodSeconds` .Values.global.proxy.readinessPeriodSeconds }}
          failureThreshold: {{ annotation .ObjectMeta `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/failureThreshold` .Values.global.proxy.readinessFailureThreshold }}
        {{ end -}}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: {{ .Values.global.proxy.privileged }}
          capabilities:
            {{ if eq (annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/interceptionMode` .ProxyConfig.InterceptionMode) `TPROXY` -}}
            add:
            - NET_ADMIN
            {{- end }}
            drop:
            - ALL
          privileged: {{ .Values.global.proxy.privileged }}
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: {{ not .Values.global.proxy.enableCoreDump }}
          runAsGroup: 1337
          {{ if eq (annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/interceptionMode` .ProxyConfig.InterceptionMode) `TPROXY` -}}
          runAsNonRoot: false
          runAsUser: 0
          {{- else -}}
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1337
          {{- end }}
        resources:
          {{ if or (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPU`) (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemory`) -}}
          requests:
            {{ if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPU`) -}}
            cpu: "{{ index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/proxyCPU` }}"
            {{ end}}
            {{ if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemory`) -}}
            memory: "{{ index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/proxyMemory` }}"
            {{ end }}
        {{ else -}}
      {{- if .Values.global.proxy.resources }}
          {{ toYaml .Values.global.proxy.resources | indent 4 }}
      {{- end }}
        {{  end -}}
        volumeMounts:
        {{ if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/bootstrapOverride`) }}
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/custom-bootstrap
          name: custom-bootstrap-volume
        {{- end }}
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/proxy
          name: istio-envoy
        {{- if .Values.global.sds.enabled }}
        - mountPath: /var/run/sds
          name: sds-uds-path
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
          name: istio-token
        {{- if .Values.global.sds.customTokenDirectory }}
        - mountPath: "{{ .Values.global.sds.customTokenDirectory -}}"
          name: custom-sds-token
          readOnly: true
        {{- end }}
        {{- else }}
        - mountPath: /etc/certs/
          name: istio-certs
          readOnly: true
        {{- end }}
        {{- if and (eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "lightstep") .Values.global.tracer.lightstep.cacertPath }}
        - mountPath: {{ directory .ProxyConfig.GetTracing.GetLightstep.GetCacertPath }}
          name: lightstep-certs
          readOnly: true
        {{- end }}
          {{- if isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/userVolumeMount` }}
          {{ range $index, $value := fromJSON (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/userVolumeMount`) }}
        - name: "{{  $index }}"
          {{ toYaml $value | indent 4 }}
          {{ end }}
          {{- end }}
      volumes:
      {{- if (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/bootstrapOverride`) }}
      - name: custom-bootstrap-volume
        configMap:
          name: {{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/bootstrapOverride` "" }}
      {{- end }}
      - emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
        name: istio-envoy
      {{- if .Values.global.sds.enabled }}
      - name: sds-uds-path
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/sds
      - name: istio-token
        projected:
          sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              path: istio-token
              expirationSeconds: 43200
              audience: {{ .Values.global.sds.token.aud }}
      {{- if .Values.global.sds.customTokenDirectory }}
      - name: custom-sds-token
        secret:
          secretName: sdstokensecret
      {{- end }}
      {{- else }}
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          optional: true
          {{ if eq .Spec.ServiceAccountName "" }}
          secretName: istio.default
          {{ else -}}
          secretName: {{  printf "istio.%s" .Spec.ServiceAccountName }}
          {{  end -}}
        {{- if isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/userVolume` }}
        {{range $index, $value := fromJSON (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `sidecar.istio.io/userVolume`) }}
      - name: "{{ $index }}"
        {{ toYaml $value | indent 2 }}
        {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if and (eq .Values.global.proxy.tracer "lightstep") .Values.global.tracer.lightstep.cacertPath }}
      - name: lightstep-certs
        secret:
          optional: true
          secretName: lightstep.cacert
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.global.podDNSSearchNamespaces }}
      dnsConfig:
        searches:
          {{- range .Values.global.podDNSSearchNamespaces }}
          - {{ render . }}
          {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
    injectedAnnotations:
  values: '{"certmanager":{"enabled":false,"hub":"quay.io/jetstack","image":"cert-manager-controller","namespace":"istio-system","tag":"v0.6.2"},"clusterResources":true,"cni":{"namespace":"istio-system"},"galley":{"enableAnalysis":false,"enabled":false,"image":"galley","namespace":"istio-system"},"gateways":{"istio-egressgateway":{"autoscaleEnabled":true,"enabled":false,"env":{"ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE":"sni-dnat"},"namespace":"istio-system","ports":[{"name":"http2","port":80},{"name":"https","port":443},{"name":"tls","port":15443,"targetPort":15443}],"secretVolumes":[{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/egressgateway-certs","name":"egressgateway-certs","secretName":"istio-egressgateway-certs"},{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/egressgateway-ca-certs","name":"egressgateway-ca-certs","secretName":"istio-egressgateway-ca-certs"}],"type":"ClusterIP","zvpn":{"enabled":true,"suffix":"global"}},"istio-ingressgateway":{"applicationPorts":"","autoscaleEnabled":true,"debug":"info","domain":"","enabled":false,"env":{"ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE":"sni-dnat"},"meshExpansionPorts":[{"name":"tcp-pilot-grpc-tls","port":15011,"targetPort":15011},{"name":"tcp-citadel-grpc-tls","port":8060,"targetPort":8060},{"name":"tcp-dns-tls","port":853,"targetPort":853}],"namespace":"istio-system","ports":[{"name":"status-port","port":15020,"targetPort":15020},{"name":"http2","port":80,"targetPort":80},{"name":"https","port":443},{"name":"kiali","port":15029,"targetPort":15029},{"name":"prometheus","port":15030,"targetPort":15030},{"name":"grafana","port":15031,"targetPort":15031},{"name":"tracing","port":15032,"targetPort":15032},{"name":"tls","port":15443,"targetPort":15443}],"sds":{"enabled":false,"image":"node-agent-k8s","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"2000m","memory":"1024Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"128Mi"}}},"secretVolumes":[{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs","name":"ingressgateway-certs","secretName":"istio-ingressgateway-certs"},{"mountPath":"/etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs","name":"ingressgateway-ca-certs","secretName":"istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs"}],"type":"LoadBalancer","zvpn":{"enabled":true,"suffix":"global"}}},"global":{"arch":{"amd64":2,"ppc64le":2,"s390x":2},"certificates":[],"configNamespace":"istio-system","configValidation":true,"controlPlaneSecurityEnabled":true,"defaultNodeSelector":{},"defaultPodDisruptionBudget":{"enabled":true},"defaultResources":{"requests":{"cpu":"10m"}},"disablePolicyChecks":true,"enableHelmTest":false,"enableTracing":false,"enabled":true,"hub":"docker.io/istio","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","imagePullSecrets":[],"istioNamespace":"istio-system","k8sIngress":{"enableHttps":false,"enabled":false,"gatewayName":"ingressgateway"},"localityLbSetting":{"enabled":true},"logAsJson":true,"logging":{"level":"default:warn"},"meshExpansion":{"enabled":false,"useILB":false},"meshNetworks":{},"mtls":{"auto":false,"enabled":false},"multiCluster":{"clusterName":"","enabled":false},"namespace":"istio-system","network":"","omitSidecarInjectorConfigMap":false,"oneNamespace":false,"operatorManageWebhooks":false,"outboundTrafficPolicy":{"mode":"ALLOW_ANY"},"policyCheckFailOpen":false,"policyNamespace":"istio-system","priorityClassName":"","prometheusNamespace":"istio-system","proxy":{"accessLogEncoding":"JSON","accessLogFile":"","accessLogFormat":"","autoInject":"disabled","clusterDomain":"cluster.local","componentLogLevel":"misc:error","concurrency":2,"dnsRefreshRate":"300s","enableCoreDump":false,"envoyAccessLogService":{"enabled":false},"envoyMetricsService":{"enabled":false,"tcpKeepalive":{"interval":"10s","probes":3,"time":"10s"},"tlsSettings":{"mode":"DISABLE","subjectAltNames":[]}},"envoyStatsd":{"enabled":false},"excludeIPRanges":"","excludeInboundPorts":"","excludeOutboundPorts":"","image":"proxyv2","includeIPRanges":"10.33.0.0/16,10.32.128.0/20","includeInboundPorts":"*","kubevirtInterfaces":"","logLevel":"warning","privileged":false,"protocolDetectionTimeout":"100ms","readinessFailureThreshold":30,"readinessInitialDelaySeconds":1,"readinessPeriodSeconds":2,"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"500m","memory":"512Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"128Mi"}},"statusPort":15020,"tracer":"zipkin"},"proxy_init":{"image":"proxyv2","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"50Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"10m","memory":"10Mi"}}},"sds":{"enabled":false,"token":{"aud":"istio-ca"},"udsPath":""},"securityNamespace":"istio-system","tag":"1.4.6","telemetryNamespace":"istio-system","tracer":{"datadog":{"address":"$(HOST_IP):8126"},"lightstep":{"accessToken":"","address":"","cacertPath":"","secure":true},"zipkin":{"address":""}},"trustDomain":"cluster.local","useMCP":false},"grafana":{"accessMode":"ReadWriteMany","contextPath":"/grafana","dashboardProviders":{"dashboardproviders.yaml":{"apiVersion":1,"providers":[{"disableDeletion":false,"folder":"istio","name":"istio","options":{"path":"/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/istio"},"orgId":1,"type":"file"}]}},"datasources":{"datasources.yaml":{"apiVersion":1}},"enabled":false,"env":{},"envSecrets":{},"image":{"repository":"grafana/grafana","tag":"6.4.3"},"ingress":{"enabled":false,"hosts":["grafana.local"]},"namespace":"istio-system","nodeSelector":{},"persist":false,"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"replicaCount":1,"security":{"enabled":false,"passphraseKey":"passphrase","secretName":"grafana","usernameKey":"username"},"service":{"annotations":{},"externalPort":3000,"name":"http","type":"ClusterIP"},"storageClassName":"","tolerations":[]},"istio_cni":{"enabled":false,"repair":{"enabled":true}},"istiocoredns":{"coreDNSImage":"coredns/coredns","coreDNSPluginImage":"istio/coredns-plugin:0.2-istio-1.1","coreDNSTag":"1.6.2","enabled":false,"namespace":"istio-system"},"kiali":{"contextPath":"/kiali","createDemoSecret":false,"dashboard":{"passphraseKey":"passphrase","secretName":"kiali","usernameKey":"username","viewOnlyMode":false},"enabled":false,"hub":"quay.io/kiali","ingress":{"enabled":false,"hosts":["kiali.local"]},"namespace":"istio-system","nodeSelector":{},"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"replicaCount":1,"security":{"cert_file":"/kiali-cert/cert-chain.pem","enabled":false,"private_key_file":"/kiali-cert/key.pem"},"tag":"v1.9"},"mixer":{"adapters":{"kubernetesenv":{"enabled":true},"prometheus":{"enabled":true,"metricsExpiryDuration":"10m"},"stackdriver":{"auth":{"apiKey":"","appCredentials":false,"serviceAccountPath":""},"enabled":false,"tracer":{"enabled":false,"sampleProbability":1}},"stdio":{"enabled":false,"outputAsJson":false},"useAdapterCRDs":false},"policy":{"adapters":{"kubernetesenv":{"enabled":true},"useAdapterCRDs":false},"autoscaleEnabled":true,"enabled":false,"image":"mixer","namespace":"istio-system","sessionAffinityEnabled":false},"telemetry":{"autoscaleEnabled":true,"enabled":false,"env":{"GOMAXPROCS":"6"},"image":"mixer","loadshedding":{"latencyThreshold":"100ms","mode":"enforce"},"namespace":"istio-system","nodeSelector":{},"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"replicaCount":1,"reportBatchMaxEntries":100,"reportBatchMaxTime":"1s","sessionAffinityEnabled":false,"tolerations":[],"useMCP":true}},"nodeagent":{"enabled":false,"image":"node-agent-k8s","namespace":"istio-system"},"pilot":{"appNamespaces":[],"autoscaleEnabled":true,"autoscaleMax":5,"autoscaleMin":1,"configMap":true,"configNamespace":"istio-config","cpu":{"targetAverageUtilization":80},"enableProtocolSniffingForInbound":false,"enableProtocolSniffingForOutbound":true,"enabled":true,"env":{},"image":"pilot","ingress":{"ingressClass":"istio","ingressControllerMode":"OFF","ingressService":"istio-ingressgateway"},"keepaliveMaxServerConnectionAge":"30m","meshNetworks":{"networks":{}},"namespace":"istio-system","nodeSelector":{},"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"policy":{"enabled":false},"replicaCount":1,"tolerations":[],"traceSampling":1,"useMCP":false},"prometheus":{"contextPath":"/prometheus","enabled":false,"hub":"docker.io/prom","ingress":{"enabled":false,"hosts":["prometheus.local"]},"namespace":"istio-system","nodeSelector":{},"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"replicaCount":1,"retention":"6h","scrapeInterval":"15s","security":{"enabled":true},"tag":"v2.12.0","tolerations":[]},"security":{"dnsCerts":{"istio-pilot-service-account.istio-control":"istio-pilot.istio-control"},"enableNamespacesByDefault":true,"enabled":true,"image":"citadel","namespace":"istio-system","selfSigned":true,"trustDomain":"cluster.local"},"sidecarInjectorWebhook":{"alwaysInjectSelector":[],"enableNamespacesByDefault":false,"enabled":true,"image":"sidecar_injector","injectLabel":"istio-injection","injectedAnnotations":{},"lifecycle":{},"namespace":"istio-system","neverInjectSelector":[],"nodeSelector":{},"objectSelector":{"autoInject":true,"enabled":false},"podAnnotations":{},"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"replicaCount":1,"resources":{},"rewriteAppHTTPProbe":false,"rollingMaxSurge":"100%","rollingMaxUnavailable":"25%","selfSigned":false,"tolerations":[]},"telemetry":{"enabled":true,"v1":{"enabled":true},"v2":{"enabled":false,"prometheus":{"enabled":true},"stackdriver":{"configOverride":{},"enabled":false,"logging":false,"monitoring":false,"topology":false}}},"tracing":{"enabled":false,"ingress":{"enabled":false},"jaeger":{"accessMode":"ReadWriteMany","enabled":false,"hub":"docker.io/jaegertracing","memory":{"max_traces":50000},"namespace":"istio-system","persist":false,"spanStorageType":"badger","storageClassName":"","tag":"1.14"},"nodeSelector":{},"opencensus":{"exporters":{"stackdriver":{"enable_tracing":true}},"hub":"docker.io/omnition","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"1","memory":"2Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"200m","memory":"400Mi"}},"tag":"0.1.9"},"podAntiAffinityLabelSelector":[],"podAntiAffinityTermLabelSelector":[],"provider":"jaeger","service":{"annotations":{},"externalPort":9411,"name":"http-query","type":"ClusterIP"},"zipkin":{"hub":"docker.io/openzipkin","javaOptsHeap":700,"maxSpans":500000,"node":{"cpus":2},"probeStartupDelay":200,"queryPort":9411,"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"300m","memory":"900Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"150m","memory":"900Mi"}},"tag":"2.14.2"}},"version":""}'
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    app: sidecar-injector
    istio: sidecar-injector
    operator.istio.io/component: Injector
    operator.istio.io/managed: Reconcile
    operator.istio.io/version: 1.4.6
    release: istio
  name: cm-test-toshi
```

2. Apply patch

```
$ kubectl patch configmap/cm-test-toshi --type merge -p '{
  "data":{
    "config":{
      "template":{
        "containers":[{
          "name":"istio-proxy",
          "lifecycle":{
            "preStop":{
              "exec":{
                "command":["/bin/sh", "-c", "while [ $(netstat -plunt | grep tcp | grep -v envoy | wc -l | xargs) -ne 0]; do sleep 1; done"]
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

## Anything else we need to know?:

## Environment:

- Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): v1.14.10-dispatcher
- Cloud provider or hardware configuration: v1.14.10-gke.17

Answer (score 1):

According to [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#alternate-forms-of-the-kubectl-patch-command) documentation:

> ### Alternate forms of the kubectl patch command
>
> The  `kubectl patch`  command takes YAML or JSON. It can take the patch as a file or directly on the command line.
>
> Create a file named  `patch-file.json`  that has this content:
>
> ```
> {
>    "spec": {
>       "template": {
>          "spec": {
>             "containers": [
>                {
>                   "name": "patch-demo-ctr-2",
>                   "image": "redis"
>                }
>             ]
>          }
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> The following commands are equivalent:
>
> ```sh
> kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-file.yaml)"
> kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch 'spec:\n template:\n  spec:\n   containers:\n   - name: patch-demo-ctr-2\n     image: redis'
>
> kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-file.json)"
> kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [{"name": "patch-demo-ctr-2","image": "redis"}]}}}}'
> ```

The method You are trying to use is not supported.

So You can use `gsed` to stream the data as You mentioned. Or convert to a template like suggested from documentation. Or put the data into a file and `cat` it like in example above.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a BLANK character right AFTER each semi-colon.

In other words.. there should be a BLANK character BEFORE each '{' character

That's what your error message also says.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this one and the error I encountered disappeared, but another one happened. Do you think this type of patch is supported?


$ kubectl patch configmap/cm-test-toshi -n kouzoh-echo-jp-dev --type merge -p '{"data": {"config": {"template": {"containers": [{"name": "istio-proxy", "lifecycle": {"preStop": {"exec": {"command": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while [ $(netstat -plunt | grep tcp | grep -v envoy | wc -l | xargs) -ne 0]; do sleep 1; done"]}}}}]}}'

Error from server: Invalid JSON Patch

Comment: The embedded command is Not working (because of single-quote and shell).  Try to manually run the command and manually put in the value into the JSON and see if it works.